# class_names from tensorflow image_dataset_from_directory appeared to be a matrix instead of vector

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I tried to input custom image data to my image classifier using `tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory()` to automate image labeling based on the names of subdirectories. The code was executed successfully but then it turned out that the image was labeled with a [batch_size, 3] matrix, which I am also not sure where the number 3 came from (maybe the channel?). It impacts my image can't be labeled from this way.

This is my code:

```
import tensorflow.keras as tfk
datadir = '/content/rockpaperscissors'

train_ds = tfk.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    datadir,
    labels =  'inferred',
    label_mode = 'categorical',
    batch_size = 10,
    image_size = (150, 150),
    shuffle = True,
    seed = 123,
    validation_split = 0.3,
    subset = 'training'
)

val_ds = tfk.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    datadir,
    labels = 'inferred',
    label_mode = 'categorical',
    batch_size = 10,
    image_size = (150, 150),
    shuffle = True,
    seed = 123,
    validation_split = 0.3,
    subset = 'validation'
)
```

then I checked the conformity of the number of images and labels per batch

```
for image_batch, labels_batch in train_ds:
  print(image_batch.shape)
  print(labels_batch.shape)
  break
```

it outputs

```
(10, 150, 150, 3)
(10, 3)
```

Is anybody know how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: *I am also not sure where the number 3 came from*, maybe you have 3 classes?

Comment: yeah, but based on the tutorial here (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images), only the batch_size value should be output for label_batch.shape

Comment: You are using label mode as **categorical**, tutorial uses default value **int**.

Comment: oh right, I tried it and it worked. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

(10, 150, 150, 3): Here 3 is the number of image channels which is 3 because it is RGB. Generally, it is (samplesxHxWxc)

(10, 3): Here 3 is the number of classes in your dataset